# ReactQuery Typescript custom queries builder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-query

I'm trying to build simplified query builder for my react query queries but I'm having problems with TypeScript. I'm really bad with TS, still learning but well...

Trying to leverage latests posts from TkDodo about RQ keys and adding simplified query usage with that. The problem I have is with the config that I want to pass if needed.
When I remove the `...config` prop the `LocationEvents` type is correctly typed in

```
  const events = useQuery(locationsQueries.events.all())
  events.data.locationEvents <-- Without the ...config TS is happy
```

But with `...config` TS complains
`TS2339: Property 'locationEvents' does not exist on type 'unknown'.`

```
import { QueryObserverOptions } from '@tanstack/react-query'
import { get } from '../request/request'

type LocationEvents = {
  locationEvents: Array<LocationEvent>
}

export const locationsQueries = {
  events: {
    all: (config: QueryObserverOptions = {}) => ({
      queryKey: [{ scope: 'locations', type: 'all' }] as const,
      queryFn: () => get('/locations/events').resolve<LocationEvents>(),
      ...config,
    }),
    byLocation: (locationId: string, config: QueryObserverOptions = {}) => ({
      queryKey: [
        { scope: 'locations', type: 'byLocation', locationId },
      ] as const,
      queryFn: () =>
        get(`/locations/${locationId}/events`).resolve<LocationEvents>(),
      ...config,
    }),
  },
}
```

And here is request

```
class RequestBuilder {
  ...

  async resolve<T extends unknown>(): Promise<T> {}
}

export function get(url): RequestBuilder {
  return new RequestBuilder(url, 'GET')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `UseQueryOptions` instead of `QueryObserverOptions`